# Command to display Memory usage, Disk Usage, CPU Load and Uptime

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, display-settings

I have this at the moment:

```
while True:

    # Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
    draw.rectangle((0, 0, oled.width, oled.height), outline=0, fill=0)

    cmd = "hostname -I | cut -d\' \' -f1"
    IP = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
    cmd = "top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf \"CPU: %.2f\", $(NF-2)}'"
    CPU = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
    cmd = "free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf \"Mem: %s/%sMB %.2f%%\", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'"
    MemUsage = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
    cmd = "df -h | awk '$NF==\"/\"{printf \"Disk: %d/%dGB %s\", $3,$2,$5}'"
    Disk = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
    cmd = "vcgencmd measure_temp |cut -f 2 -d '='"
    temp = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )

    # Pi Stats Display
    draw.text((0, 0), "IP: " + str(IP,'utf-8'), font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((0, 16), str(CPU,'utf-8') + "%", font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((80, 16), str(temp,'utf-8') , font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((0, 32), str(MemUsage,'utf-8'), font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((0, 48), str(Disk,'utf-8'), font=font, fill=255)
```

1. I want to add uptime to a line with IP, showing for example: IP: 127.0.0.1 UP: d / h / m.
2. How do I make Memory write it in GB instead of MB?

Comment: it seems you have unblalance `"` after `-f1`. Is that intended? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: and what does your attempt do? show errors? ... `-d\' \'` - surely that should be `-d' '`

Comment: you can read that CPU loadavg from `/proc/loadavg` instead of that complex `top` line - `man free` to see how to use `free`, and `man uptime` to get uptime (which you can also use to get the loadavg)